# React-Select return value instead of the whole option object

Tags: react-select

I'm using React-Select and Zod for validation. I have the following component so far:

```
interface IFormInputs {
    title: string
    content: string
    jobCategory: string
}

const schema = zod.object({
    title: zod.string(),
    content: zod.string(),
    jobCategory: zod.string(),
});

const PostNewJobForm = () => {
    const {control, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm<IFormInputs>({
        resolver: zodResolver(schema)
    });

    const onSubmit = (data: IFormInputs) => {
        console.log(data)
    };

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Form.Group controlId="jobAddForm.JobCategory">
                <Controller
                    name={"jobCategory"}
                    control={control}
                    as={JobCategorySelect}
                    options={options}
                    defaultValue={options[0]}
                />
                {errors.jobCategory && errors.jobCategory.message}
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>
    );
};
```

When we select an option, we receive an object with the following error: `Expected string, received object`. I would like to return object's value which is of type `{ value, label }`

How can we populate jobCategory with the selected object's value instead of the whole object?